# Failed Connect Local Host (Desktop)

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit

Hi using retrofit api call method but am using local ip address still am not get proper response. if i tested in postman i got correct json response but in android studio am facing this connection issue.

**Error...>
HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.52 (port 5000) from /192.168.1.54 (port 58978) after 60000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)**

Comment: Which is the ip you put in Retrofit? Have you using emulator or real device?

Comment: am use local host ip address (192.168.1.52:5000) in retrofit. and am using real device. both device and system are connected in same network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem before and I remember that if you have your server running in the same network as the app you need to use 10.0.2.2:{PORT} or the laptop network IP (in case you run it on a real device).

So your endpoint in your case should be :

```
//For real device
private const val BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.51:5000/"
//For emulator
private const val BASE_URL = "http://172.0.2.2:8080/"
```

Check please that is not problem with your Firewall sometimes you have to allow access (restarting PC would be enought to know if it's the problem)

Comment: You correct..... in real device am use, what you say like that only am used                                  
    BASE_URL = " http://192.168.1.52:5000/......" but failed to connect....You try to given any other idea to solve this problem please

Comment: Are you using the http://? And also the last "/"?

Comment: Yaa am using bro same after http // and also at the end  /

Comment: Finally its working bro today start pc at the time Firewall ask allow access permission        I given the permission its working now  Json response come with status code 200  and  Thank you bro. for your support

Answer (score 1):

It can be that firewall on your pc blocks the connection.

Or you have bound your server to localhost/127.0.0.1.

Do not bind your server to an ip address.

Comment: Exactly bro, finally today morning start my pc firewall will ask permission to access given allow that's working and also get json response with 200 status .